# In Laravel how to make Mutiple Dashboards for different clients names?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel.
I am trying to understand the concept of making Multiple Dashboards for different clients names?
I currently have a drop down using a the below:

```
<div class="select_dropdown">
  <select class="select" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                        <option disabled selected>Clients</option>

    @foreach($clients as $client)
    <option value="/dash/{{$client->ID}}"> {{$client->Name}} </option>
    @endforeach

   </select>
</div>
```

This is within the app.blade.php which is part of the UI that exists on every page.

Next I have a Route within the wep.php file that has :

```
Route::get('/dash/{id}', 'DashController@index');
```

Then I have a controller that reads:

```
public function index() { 
        
        return view('dash.maindash');

    }
```

I was able to use :

```
@if (Request::is('dash/1'))  
Page using a if Statement within html
@endif
```

To change what the user sees based on the URL but there are multiple clients to choose from.
Would it be normal to have multiple if statements to do this or am I doing to much manual style work here? Also Am I using the Select Tag properly to select and change the URL ? I am not sure if this approach is right and i am missing some important routing concepts.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are passing id of client in a route i.e

```
Route::get('/dash/{id}', 'DashController@index');
```

Now in controller , get that id:

```
public function index($id) { 
       $client_id = $id;
// now u can fetch details of client having passed id and u can pass that in view using compact
        $client_details = [
             'data' => 'goes here',
        ];
        return view('dash.maindash',compact('client_details'));

    }
```

In maindash.blade.php:
you can dynamically render details of client therefore there will be different dashboard for client. E.g:

```
<p>Client name: {{ $client_details['name'] }}</p>
```

Comment: What does the 'data' => 'goes here', and the compact () mean? What do they represent ?

Comment: compact is a way of passing data from controller to view like if i had client of id 1 and $client_detail=Client::find(1);  return view('dash.maindash',compact('client_detail')); now i can access that client-detail in view this way {{$client_detail->name}}

Comment: `compact('client_details')` is equivalent to `['client_details' => $client_details]`

Comment: and the `'data' => 'goes here' ` means just put whatever data you need in the view in that array